# How should I invoke a packaged spring project from another spring project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties-file

I have two spring projects both using maven. The first is a client for some api and the second is a console program that, in part, utilises that client.

I have packaged up the client into a jar and referenced it in the pom for the console program.

I have managed to get this working, just about, but I am not very happy with the solution:

**1)** The first problem I ran into was that each of the context xml files were named "applicationContext.xml". Therefore, I couldn't work out any way to reference the context file in the client, without renaming it to something else e.g. clientContext.xml. This works but is there any other way to reference it explicitly?

**2)** The next issue was how to invoke the clientContext.xml from within the console program. To do this, I have added `<import resource="osrdClientContext.xml"/>` to the applicationContext.xml of the console program and this seems to allow it to correctly find all of the defined beans. I'm not sure if this is best practice though?

**3)** Within clientContext.xml, I need to reference a properties file and so have the line `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:api.properties" />`. This works when running the client on its own but appears to get ignored (or fails to find the file) when running the console program. The api.properties file is in the root of the packaged jar for the client and the jar is in the classpath of the console program. The only workaround I have found is to manually copy the properties file into the console program, at which point it is found without any problem.

**4)** Both projects have a resources directory with sub-directories "dev", "beta" and "prod". This allows me to define different properties depending on the maven profile I want to run against. This works fine for the individual projects but when I package the client, it only includes the properties files for the profile I am running against (which makes sense). However, that then means if I run the console project against profile "beta", it will still run the client against whatever profile it was packaged against. It would be handy to be able to package all of the properties files and get the client to run in the same profile as whatever is depending on it. Is that possible/a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

**Ad 1:** The common place to put your JAR-based XML contexts is inside `META-INF/your/project/name` folder. You can check for example [*spring-batch-admin*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/tree/master/spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager) project. Also nowdays it is more common to name the context files *{name}-context.xml* (e.g. *central-context.xml*).

By following the advice above, you should not have problems with name conflicts. However it should be possible to overcome such problem by using [`classpath*`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wi/ldcards) pseudo protocol in your *import* definition:

```
<import resource="classpath*:do/not/put/in/root/this-can-be-duplicate.xml"/>
```

**Ad 2:** This is completely legit. You can see the same practice in the Spring Batch Admin example as linked above. Just add the `classpath:` or `classpath*:` to the resource path.

**Ad 3:** That is very strange and I have no clue to what is going on there.

**Ad 4:** This is possible to achieve via [Spring profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/#enter-bean-definition-profiles) (not Maven profiles):

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:META-INF/dev/my.properties"/>
</beans>
```

or via new [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html#expressions-beandef) support:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:META-INF/#{systemProperties['my.jvm.property']}/my.properties"/>
```

However what I like is to have a default properties and then let the main application be able to override them. This means, that your configuration will be on a single place and not inside the JAR. You can achieve this via properties hierarchy:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:META-INF/my-default.properties,classpath*:META-INF/my-optional-overrides.properties"/>
```

---

**UPDATE** just discovered that `<context:property-placeholder>` has [problems with SPeL](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7765). However you can still use SPeL (and even other property configurers) when defining the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` manually (i.e. via `<bean>`).